# Regex - Match a specific syntax and split them

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a specific regex syntax and split them so that we can match them to an equivalent value from a dictionary.

**Input:**

```
{Expr "string"}
{Expr "string"}{Expr}
```

**Current code:**

```
value.match(/\{.*\}$/g)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[{Expr "string"}]
[{Expr "string"},{Expr}]
```

Comment: You need to use non-greedy `.*?`

Comment: tried ``valueToMatch.match(/\{.*?\}$/g)`` same result

Comment: Get rid of `$`, it forces it to match all the way to the end.

Comment: That worked thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier `.*?`. And don't use `$`, because that forces it to match all the way to the end of the string.

```js
value = '{Expr "string"}{Expr}'
console.log(value.match(/\{.*?\}/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, assuming your version of JavaScript support it, would be to split the input on the following regex pattern:

```
(?<=\})(?=\{)
```

This says to split at each `}{` junction between two terms.

```js
var input = "{Expr \"string\"}{Expr}";
var parts = input.split(/(?<=\})(?=\{)/);
console.log(parts);
```